# Google Apps Script - How to get corresponding record in destination spreadsheet in onFormSubmit (Google Forms Event)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-apps-script-addon

I catch this event when a respondent sends a response

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_4

Inside this function, I want to add some information into the corresponding row (Google creates this row automatically) in the destination spreadsheet

In order to do that, **first I need to find this row**

The best way I can find at the moment is by using `sheet.getLastRow()`

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow

But there is concurrency problem with this method: Serge insas said it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17751544/2667212

> There are a few risks to use that simple "strategy" as there might be
>   concurrency issues when 2 or more people send a form simultaneously

Is there any correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution:

Easiest way is to disable automatic spreadsheet linking provided by Google and use custom linking.

#### Snippet:

```
function formSubmitInForm(e){
 const formResponse = e.response;
 const id = formResponse.getId();
 const timestamp = formResponse.getTimestamp();
 const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(/*SPREADSHEET ID*/)
    .getSheetByName(/*FORM RESPONSE SHEET*/);
 const responses = formResponse.getItemResponses().map(function(itemRes){
    return itemRes.getResponse();
 })
 sheet.appendRow([id,timestamp].concat(responses))
}
```

#### Reference:

- [FormResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response)

Comment: Thank you. But there is still the concurrency issue with this approach, I think? At the moment, I use const destinationSpreadsheetId = form.getDestinationId()
  const destinationSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSpreadsheetId)

Comment: @Hoang I'm saying disconnect the spreadsheet from the form.  Use your own spreadsheet and format and push data from form to spreadsheet using the script above.

Comment: @Hoang If you have concurrency issues, while pushing to sheet, use [lock service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock)

Comment: Thank you very much. Lock service is exactly what I need