# How do I stop Google sheet from generating duplicating forms?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am using the following Google Script code to generate a backup every time I open the file.

```
function copySheet() {
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-6", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");
  var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() + " Copy " + formattedDate;
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("18aW0o_L1jngSjZ56aKGjt29JwTE1OQZf");
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId())
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.makeCopy(name, destination));
  var ss = sh.getSheets()[0];
  ss.getRange(1,1,ss.getLastRow(),ss.getLastColumn()).setValues(ss.getRange(1,1,ss.getLastRow(),ss.getLastColumn()).getValues());
}
```

There is a form linked to this sheet and that too gets duplicated every time the form. How do I stop this from happening? I want every backup copy to be linked with the same form. How can I do it using Google Script?

If it is not possible, is there any other way to generate backup such that the form doesn't get duplicated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Link the same form to each spreadsheet

> I want every backup copy to be linked with the same form. How can I do it using Google Script?

Unfortunately, this is not possible.  A form can only be linked to one spreadsheet at a time.

### Option 1: Copy individual sheets

One way to prevent duplicate forms: instead of creating a copy of the spreadsheet, create a new blank spreadsheet, and copy the individual sheet (or sheets) to that spreadsheet.

```
/**
 * Create a new spreadsheet in the folder, and copy the sheet to it.
 */
function duplicateSpreadsheetF(filename, sourceSpreadsheet, folder) {
  // Create a new blank file
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(filename)
  // Move to the folder
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId())
  file.moveTo(folder)

  // Copy the sheets from the source
  sourceSpreadsheet.getSheets().forEach(function(sheet){
    sheet.copyTo(spreadsheet).setName(sheet.getName())
  })
 
  // Remove the default blank Sheet1
  var blankSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  if (blankSheet) spreadsheet.deleteSheet(blankSheet)

  return spreadsheet
}
```

When you just copy the individual sheet, the copy won't be linked to any form--it will just be a copy of the data on the sheet.

### Option 2: Delete the form after duplication

You can append this to your existing code.  It will iterate over all sheets on the backup copy, and unlink--then delete--any form linked to each sheet.

```
// Unlink and delete all forms that are linked to spreadsheet sh
sh.getSheets().forEach(function(sheet){
  // Get form attached to sheet
  var formUrl = sheet.getFormUrl();  // returns null if there is no linked form 
  if (formUrl) {           
    var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formUrl);

    // Unlink the form
    form.removeDestination();

    // Delete the form
    DriveApp.getFileById(form.getId()).setTrashed(true);
  }
})
```

Comment: Is there a way to create a copy of the entire spreadsheet instead of copying sheets individually? @Aaron

Comment: @Jerrymon You could iterate over all sheets, or use your current code and then delete the linked form afterward.  I've updated my answer to show both of these.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct. It is however possible to delink the form and use [`onFormSubmit` of form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1) to post form data to various spreadsheets without relying on the inbuilt form-spreadsheet link. See [sample here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57736961)

Comment: Yes, good point, you can instruct the `onFormSubmit` trigger to append the row to each Spreadsheet.  However, beware that if you add questions to the form, the target sheets won't automatically update to reflect those questions as they do with linked forms, so you'll have to handle those changes in your code.